# How do you write multi-line function definitions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

how do you usually write functions with a lot of parameters?
this way:

```
function foo(
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: boolean): boolean {

....

}
```

or this way:

```
function foo(
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: boolean
): boolean {

....

}
```

?

Comment: This is a purely stylistic choice... I don't believe it is a good question for SO.

Answer (score 4):

While this is a style choice, there is something you can consider:

```
let c: number = 10

function foo(
  a: number,
  b: string) {
  c = 123
}
```

You can see that this create confusion on where the parameter list ends and where the code block starts.
I used to do this myself, but I'm considering changing to

```
function foo(
  a: number,
  b: string)
{
  c = 123
}

// or, to be more JavaScript friendly
function foo(
  a: number,
  b: string
) {
  c = 123
}
```

Again, this is about personal and team preference at the end.

Comment: plus you can use a trailing comma after `b: string` and thus make all your parameter lines consistent ;)